# pd.Series.apply keyword arguments are are a pd.series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I am using apply on a series in a dataframe to use a function with multiple keyword arguments. I am using the apply function on the first input (called sk), then the other arguments I have in other columns of my dataframe. My apply line looks like this:

```
Updates['Action'] = Updates['sk'].apply(RCCheck.nsamcheck, reportseries=Updates['reportseries'],rssd=Updates['rssd'], username=username, pw=password)
```

I get an the error (the function is querying an Oracle SQL database):

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

However, if I use:

```
 Updates['Action'] = Updates['sk'].apply(RCCheck.nsamcheck, reportseries='abcd',rssd='1234', username=username, pw=password)
```

It works no problem, but the point of using the pd.series references is so that it could move down each row and return he function output. Report series and rssd vary per row. I can't really share more of the code so I apologize for not sharing a whole lot.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Since you are trying to create an extra row which depends on multiple columns, I think you should use apply in the whole dataframe rather than on a particular column. You can access each column inside the apply func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the function to a series, apply it to the whole dataframe.

```
def my_new_func(row):
    return RCCheck.nsamcheck(
        reportseries=row['reportseries'], rssd=row['rssd'], username=username, pw=password
)

Updates['Action'] = Updates.apply(my_new_func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have more columns than just the ones used in the function though, would that cause a problem?

Comment: I don't think that will cause any issues.

Comment: Ok so I added it and added the 'sk' field (the first argument in the function) before reportseries. Then I get an error that says KeyError: ('sk', 'occurred at index User_District'). User_District is an unrelated column in my df.

Comment: Added axis=1 to .apply, that seems to have helped.

Comment: I missed the `axis=1` part! I've updated the answer.